# How to erase a QGraphicsItem from QGraphicsView using QPushButton

Tags: sqlite, qt5, qtableview, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am building a major user interface but I am stuck on a problem and in order to shrink the problem I build a small working example that carries exactly the problem.

After the user creates a new `.db` file using the icon and saving for example to Desktop it is possible to load images(only in `.png` format for now) in the `QGraphicsView` and cliking on the `checkbox` to enable from `Right: Drag` to `Right:Select` it is possible to draw boxes on the image. With a `right click` inside the drawn box we can open a `QDialog` that asks to name the extracted image from the box. The image is stored in the `QTableView` as shown in the small working example below:

[image: sql]

**The problem**:
I tried several ways to erase the box (and the related index on the `QTableView` of the related box) but none of them was successful. 
With the use of the "Erase Square" `QPushButton` I am trying to erase the box. Every box can be re-activated by just left `double-clicking` within the interested box. See below what I am trying to achieve:

[image: problem]

I draw the box on the `QGraphicsView` and right mouse click to capture the image from the box:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
      {
        this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),
                this, SLOT(ShowContextMenu(const QPoint &)));
      }
}

void MainWindow::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    leftScene->clearSelection();     // Selections would also render to the file
    leftScene->setSceneRect(leftScene->itemsBoundingRect());    // Re-shrink the scene to it's bounding contents
    QImage image(leftScene->sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);  // Create the image with the exact size of the shrunk scene
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);     // Start all pixels transparent

    QPainter painter(&image);
    leftScene->render(&painter);
    QImage subimage = image.copy(QRect(start.toPoint(), end.toPoint()));

    clipSceneDialog d(this);
    d.show();
    d.setImage(subimage);
    d.setHeaderImage(currentLeftImagePath);
    d.setBoundingBox(QRect(start.toPoint(), end.toPoint()));

    if(d.exec() == QDialog::Rejected) {
        return;
    } else {
        //
    }
    Param result = d.getData();
    Parameters* param = new Parameters(result);
    mDatabaseLeftCamera->addItem(param);
    mModelLeftCamera->select();
    ui->tableView->show();
}
```

Draw as many boxes as the user wants:

```
void MainWindow::onRubberBandUpdate(const QRect &viewportRect,
                                    const QPointF &fromScenePoint,
                                    const QPointF &toScenePoint)
{
    if(viewportRect.isNull() && fromScenePoint.isNull() && toScenePoint.isNull() && imageLoaded)
    {
        if(currentSelection >= 0)
                selections[currentSelection]->setActiveState(false);
            QRectF select;
            select.setCoords(start.x(), start.y(), end.x(), end.y());
            square = new Square(select);
            square->setActiveState(true);
            currentSelection = selections.size();
            selections.append(square);
            leftScene->addItem(square->getGraphics());
            ui->graphicsView->show();
    }
    else
    {
        start = fromScenePoint;
        end = toScenePoint;
    }
}
```

After drawing several boxes the user decides to reactivate one of the boxes by double-cliking within the box:

```
void MainWindow::onSceneDoubleClick(QPointF point)
{
    qDebug() << "Click!";
        QList<QGraphicsItem*> foundItems = leftScene->items(point);
        if(foundItems.size() > 0 && foundItems[0]->group() != nullptr)
        {
            qDebug() << "Found";
            int i = 0;
            for(i=0;i<selections.size();i++)
            {
                qDebug() << "Iterate";
                if(selections[i]->getGraphics() == foundItems[0]->group())
                {
                    qDebug() << "Target";
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(currentSelection >= 0)
                selections[currentSelection]->setActiveState(false);
            currentSelection = i;
            selections[currentSelection]->setActiveState(true);
        }
}
```

The user decides to erase the re-activated square:

```
void MainWindow::on_eraseSquare_clicked()
{
    clearSceneLeft();
}


void MainWindow::clearSceneLeft()
{
    if (selections.size() > 0) {
        qDeleteAll(selections);
        selections.clear();
        currentSelection = -1;
    }
    for(int p=0;p<shape.size();p++)
    {
        leftScene->removeItem(shape[p]);
        delete shape[p];
    }
        shape.clear();
}
```

But this is not working and nothing happens. Additionally because the box corresponds to an `SQL` reference on the `QTableView` I dont know how that could be connected in the `SQL` class.

I have been trying for many days to solve this problem and am running out of ideas. Thanks for shedding light on this problem or point in the right direction. 
If you would like to try the small example interface you can do it from [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/reference/src/master/)

Comment: After compiling your examples I was able to run your program. But after trying to add an row to the table of images it crashes. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks for helping Aleph0, couple of steps to use the `.ui`: 1) create a database file using icon at top right (try.db for example) and put it on your Desktop; 2) You will see headers appearing on the `QTableView` after creating the `.db` file; 3) upload a `.png` image; 4) check the `Left:Drag` checkbox to turn it into a `Right:Select` option; 5) draw boxes on the image; 6) right click in the box to extract the image: a `Dialog box` will appear; 7) give a name to the extracted image [see here](https://i.imgur.com/KfRGbhr.png); 8) Accept and you will see the creation of the new row

Comment: Also on `MainWindow` inside constructor erase from line 43 `//temporary folder` to line 53. It should not cause anything anyway because it is not active  but just to make sure it is not crashing because it contains my old debugging statements.

Comment: Other than that, it should run and allow you to create the row

Comment: I think that your dataLeftCamera class needs at least a function like: `bool dataLeftCamera::removeItem(int itemId)`?

Comment: Ok thanks I am implement a `removeItem(int itemId)` but I have a question, how should that be connected on `MainWindow`, specifically on `void MainWindow::on_eraseSquare_clicked()`

Comment: You should consider to link the `QGraphicsRectItem*` and `Square*` to their corresponding `QModelIndex` to keep everything in sync. Maybe your `Square` class needs a `setModelIndex(const QModelIndex&)`function. Now the selected `Square` knows to which index it would belong.

Comment: Thanks, and do I have to subclass `QTableView` to use `removeRows` as explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/itemviews-addressbook.html) or that is uncorrelated with the `Square` class? Sorry to ask but I am not very familiar with `QModelIndex`.

Comment: You need to remove rows from the model. The function is already there in the `QSqlTableModel`.  Actually, I think that it would be helpful for you to consider the left hand side screen with all these red rectangles as just a different view. Just like the `QTableView` on the right hand side.